# how to get multiple streams based on the same stream controller in flutter?

Tags: dart, stream, flutter, bloc, stream-builder

I have a Bloc class that needs three streams based on the same stream controller.

```
class TodoBloc {

  final _todoController = StreamController<List<TodoModel>>();

  get allTodoStream => _todoController.stream;

  get activeTodoStream => _todoController.stream
          .map<List<TodoModel>>(
              (list) => list.where((item) => item.state == 0));

  get completedTodoStream => _todoController.stream
          .map<List<TodoModel>>(
              (list) => list.where((item) => item.state == 1));}
```

it's a list of to-dos which have states. I'd like to retrieve the to-dos with an active state in a stream separate from the one that retrieves the other states.

I have a method that's responsible for the filtering and returns a stream depending on the filter value. here's the method:

```
Stream<List<TodoModel>> filterTodoLs(String filter) {
    if (filter == 'all') {
      return todoStream;
    } else if (filter == 'completed') {
      return completedStream;
    } else if (filter == 'active') {
      return activeStream;
    }
    return todoStream;
}
```

later to be used in a widget like the following:

```
 return StreamBuilder<List<TodoModel>>(
      stream: bloc.filterTodoLs(filter),
      builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<TodoModel>> todoSnapShot) {}
```

the snapshot is empty so far. how can i filter my original stream and return different ones depending on the filter applied to that stream?

Comment: You'll want to use a BehaviorSubject instead of a StreamController.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `StreamController.broadcast()` creates a stream that can have multiple listeners.

See https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams#broadcast-streams

The details of switching between the different filtered streams depends on context not provided in the question.

Comment: What if I have a widget wrapped in a streambuilder attached to a stream and say I am using the same widget at multiple places but change of a single widget updates to all the widgets because they all are listening to the same stream how to make the same widget listen to different streams

Comment: I have got it a single instance of that class has to be created to create a unique stream